Gitlab CE with Wasabi S3 storage not working
I am trying to setup my Gitlab CE instance to use wasabi S3 storage as the storage for all my repositories, registry as well as my backup.  I have read the documentation and although it strictly says AWS, Wasabi is fully AWS compatible.  Not sure why it is not working.  I know I am using the correct keys because I am able to login to my local computer to the bucket and read and write to it with the same creds.  I am able to reconfigure the server without any errors, but nothing gets written to the bucket.  When I attempt to create the backup manually I do get an error message as below.  My Wasabi config is as follows
# Define AWS credentials once
wasabi_connection = {
  'provider' => 'AWS',
  'region' => 'us-east-1',
  'aws_access_key_id' => 'My Access Key',
  'aws_secret_access_key' => 'My Secret Key',
  'endpoint' => 'https://s3.wasabisys.com'
}


# Repositories Storage
gitlab_rails['object_store']['enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['object_store']['remote_directory'] = 'gitlab-repository'
gitlab_rails['object_store']['connection'] = wasabi_connection

gitlab_rails['repositories_storages'] = {
  'default' => {
    'path' => '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories',
    'gitaly_address' => 'unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket',
    'object_store' => {
      'enabled' => true,
      'remote_directory' => 'gitlab-repository',
      'direct_upload' => true,
      'background_upload' => false,
      'proxy_download' => false,
      'connection' => wasabi_connection
    }
  }
}

# Artifacts Storage
gitlab_rails['artifacts_object_store'] = {
  'enabled' => true,
  'remote_directory' => 'gitlab-repository',  # Using the same bucket
  'connection' => wasabi_connection
}

# LFS Storage
gitlab_rails['lfs_object_store'] = {
  'enabled' => true,
  'remote_directory' => 'gitlab-repository',  # Using the same bucket
  'connection' => wasabi_connection
}

# Uploads Storage
gitlab_rails['uploads_object_store'] = {
  'enabled' => true,
  'remote_directory' => 'gitlab-repository',  # Using the same bucket
  'connection' => wasabi_connection
}

# Packages Storage
gitlab_rails['packages_object_store'] = {
  'enabled' => true,
  'remote_directory' => 'gitlab-repository',  # Using the same bucket
  'connection' => wasabi_connection
}

# External Diffs Storage
gitlab_rails['external_diffs_object_store'] = {
  'enabled' => true,
  'remote_directory' => 'gitlab-repository',  # Using the same bucket
  'connection' => wasabi_connection
}

# Dependency Proxy Storage
gitlab_rails['dependency_proxy_object_store'] = {
  'enabled' => true,
  'remote_directory' => 'gitlab-repository',  # Using the same bucket
  'connection' => wasabi_connection
}

# Terraform State Storage
gitlab_rails['terraform_state_object_store'] = {
  'enabled' => true,
  'remote_directory' => 'gitlab-repository',  # Using the same bucket
  'connection' => wasabi_connection
}

# Container Registry Storage
registry['storage'] = {
  's3' => {
    'accesskey' => wasabi_connection['aws_access_key_id'],
    'secretkey' => wasabi_connection['aws_secret_access_key'],
    'bucket' => 'gitlab-repository',
    'region' => wasabi_connection['region'],
    'endpoint' => wasabi_connection['endpoint']
  }
}

# Backup Storage
gitlab_rails['backup_upload_connection'] = wasabi_connection
gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory'] = 'gitlab-repository' 


gitlab-backup create --trace
** Invoke gitlab:backup:create (first_time)
** Invoke gitlab_environment (first_time)
** Execute gitlab_environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment rake aborted! Object storage for artifacts must have a bucket specified
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/object_store_settings.rb:234:in
missing_bucket_for'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/object_store_settings.rb:172:in
block in parse!'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/object_store_settings.rb:161:in
each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/object_store_settings.rb:161:in
parse!'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:963:in
<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in
load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in
block in load_config_initializer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in
instrument'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in
load_config_initializer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:620:in
block (2 levels) in class:Engine'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in
each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in
block in class:Engine'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in
instance_exec'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in
run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in
block in run_initializers'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in block in
tsort_each' /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in block
(2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:422:in block (2 levels)
in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in
each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:421:in block in
each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in
each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in
tsort_each_child' /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:415:in
call' /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:415:in
each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in block in
each_strongly_connected_component'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in call'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in
each_strongly_connected_component'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in tsort_each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in tsort_each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in
run_initializers'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in
initialize!'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/environment.rb:7:in
<top (required)>'
internal:/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in
require'
internal:/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in
require'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in
require'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/application.rb:348:in
require_environment!'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8.4/lib/rails/application.rb:506:in
block in run_tasks_blocks'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in
block in execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in
each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in
execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in
block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in
synchronize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in
invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in
invoke'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/helpers.rake:7:in
block in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in
block in execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in
each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in
execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in
block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in
synchronize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in
invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in
block in invoke_prerequisites'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in
each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in
invoke_prerequisites'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in
block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in
synchronize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in
invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in
invoke'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in
invoke_task'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in
block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in
each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in
block in top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in
run_with_threads'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in
top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in
block in run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in
standard_exception_handling'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in
run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in
<top (required)>' /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/rake:25:in load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/rake:25:in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in
load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in
kernel_load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in
run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli.rb:455:in
exec'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in
run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in
invoke_command'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:527:in
dispatch'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli.rb:35:in
dispatch'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:584:in
start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli.rb:29:in
start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/exe/bundle:28:in
block in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in
with_friendly_errors'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/exe/bundle:20:in
<top (required)>' /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in ' Tasks: TOP =>
environment root@gitlab:~#

